# Accidently installed two versions of swi-prolog, need help to fix it

Tags: uninstall

Alright, I have this problem where I installed two different versions of swi-prolog.

I manually installed swi-prolog (swipl) version 5.10.4 from a tar-file, which I see now is a stupid thing. (I can't remember why I did this exactly, but that is besides the point.)

Then I wanted to get the newest version of prolog, so I followed these steps:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:swi-prolog/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install swi-prolog
```

Now if I do

```
swipl --version
```

I get

```
SWI-Prolog version 5.10.4 for x86_64-linux
```

And if I do

```
/usr/bin/swipl --version
```

I get

```
SWI-Prolog version 6.4.1 for amd64
```

I only want the 6.4.1 version on my computer.

I searched the internet for hours, but I couldn't find out how to solve the problem. (Maybe I've been searching for the wrong terms/tags, I don't know..)

So, I found out that the 5.10.4 version can be found at /usr/local/bin/ whereas the 6.4.1 version is at /usr/bin/. Can't I just rm the 5.10.4 version from /usr/local/bin/ then? Or is that not clean, e.g. does it leave obsolete files somewhere on disk?

I just deleted the file *swipl* at */usr/local/bin/swipl* with the *rm*-command.
Now I get the 6.4.1 version whenever I call swipl, but I still wonder if this is a good solution.

The output of `type swipl` is `swipl is /usr/local/bin/swipl` and the output of `dpkg -S $(type swipl | awk '{print $3}')` is `dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern /usr/local/bin/swipl.`

I untarred the .tar-file and I ran make from the source (src folder) that was in the .tar-file. Then installed the program using `sudo make install`.

Comment: I cannot remember for sure if I did, but I think I probably did `sudo make install`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To uninstall software installed with `sudo make install` the best way to remove them is using `sudo make uninstall`.

Comment: I usually clean up my download directory after I download something. This was also the case with the .tar-file containing the source from which I ran make. I don't have the .tar-file anymore, but I'm sure I can find it to download it again. Do you suggest I should download the file again, untar it and then run `sudo make uninstall`?

Comment: Yeah, but you must make `./configure` and `make` first. Is all the same process just that at the end is `uninstall`.